# Erro ao adicionar HttpPost no controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou com um problema na hora de adicionar o atributo `[HttpPost]` no meu controller. Digo, eu consigo adicionar o atributo sem problemas, mas quando eu compilo e vou para o formulario de cadastro eu simplesmente não consigo acessar.

Eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.
>
> Não é possível encontrar o recurso.
>
> Descrição: HTTP 404. O recurso que você está procurando (ou uma de suas dependências) não pôde ser removido, seu nome foi alterado ou está temporariamente indisponível. Examine o URL e certifique-se de que está digitado corretamente.
>
> URL solicitada: /usuario/adicionar

*Informações sobre a Versão: Microsoft .NET Framework Versão:4.0.30319; Versão do ASP.NET:4.0.30319.33440*

Além disso, quando eu retiro o atributo `httppost`, eu consigo visualizar o formulario de cadastro, porém não consigo fazer o insert no banco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você adiciona o atributo HttpPost em uma action. Ela só poderá ser acessada via o método POST do protocolo HTTP.

Se o seu intuito é somente exibir o formulário. Não decore o seu método com nenhum atributo, que o padrão será GET.

O que você pode fazer é definir um método Adicionar sem nenhum atributo. Este método será acessado via GET e exibirá o formulário.

Então você cria um segundo método, por exemplo AdicionarConfirmado, decorado com os atributos HttpPost e ActionName="Adicionar"

Os métodos pode sem definidos da seguinte maneira

```
public ActionResult Adicionar() 
{ 
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName="Adicionar"]
public ActionResult AdicionarConfirmado(Cliente cliente) 
{ 
}
```

Já o seu formulário que irá salvar o registro ficaria assim:

```
<form action="Adicionar" method="post"></form>
```

Comment: public ActionResult Adicionar() 
{ 
}

Esse método é para ser sem retorno mesmo?

Comment: Consegui resolver. Era isso mesmo, obrigado!